# LiteStep shell onto WindowsCE6.0. Is it possible?

Tags: windows-ce, windows-shell

I'm looking for replace standart WinCE explorer to the [LiteStep shell](http://litestep.net/), but i'm not sure that it is possible. Can someone give me some advices about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I sincerely doubt it.  The desktop entry point and the Windows CE entry points for a shell application are vastly different, so even if the code would compile (and LiteStep almost certainly uses APIs not in Windows CE) it wouldn't do a shell replacement.

Could you rework the LiteStep code to eventually get it working on CE?  Probably, but would probably take way longer than just starting from zero and creating your Shell replacement in CE.